# How to pass value from one page to another page by clicking text on page

Tags: php, redirect

I am newbie to web programming and working on web application development(first project) where i have some text on page and after clicking this text i want to pass some fixed text to other page in PHP as explained here

Page1

```
<html>
<head>
</html>
<body>
       <a href="#" value="fixed text">some text </a>

</body>
</html>
```

Page2 should be able to get value when i click on page1. How can i implement it?

Answer (score 2):

You should pass arguments with url:

```
<a href="xyz.php?value=fixed text">some text </a>
```

And in the `xyz.php` or what ever file name for php:

```
<?php
$value = ! empty($_GET['value']) ? $_GET['value'] : '';
?>
```

Reference: PHP's [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

Whatever data you have in url query string. e.g. `xyz.php?par1=one&par2=two&par3=three`

You get key value pairs in `$_GET`.

So, you will get

`$_GET` as

```
array(
  'par1' => 'one',
  'par2' => 'two',
  'par3' => 'three'
);
```

Comment: I have updated your answer with `urlencode()` for the value and made sure the pages were named after something OP can relate to from the example supplied

Answer (score 1):

page 1

```
<html>
  <head>
 </html>
 <body>
   <a href="page2.php?val=sample" value="fixed text">some text </a>
   </body>
 </html>
```

page2.php

```
 <?php
  $value=$_GET['val'];
  ?>

<html>
  <head>
 </html>
 <body>
   <?php

    echo $value;
    ?>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Bad answer: keeping `value="fixed text"` obfuscates the answer for OP, wrongful indentation, no explanation...